# How to change color of a part of an image using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, html5-canvas

I searched a lot. But cant reach into a decision, should i use canvas api or html mapping with area tag to color part of an image on click in a specific color. Just like, link below.

[Example link](https://www.boxxerworld.com/custom-equipment/gloves/easy-gloves/custom)

Suggest me please, in which way should i go or try to make?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

[HTML Tag Area](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_area.asp)

**Edited:**
I'm not an especialist, but i don't belieave there are only way to do something. I have on my ptoject Tag Area.

I found this, maybe can help you.

[Canvas](https://jsfiddle.net/api/mdn/)

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="200" class="playable-canvas"></canvas>
<div class="playable-buttons">
  <input id="edit" type="button" value="Edit" />
  <input id="reset" type="button" value="Reset" />
</div>
<textarea id="code" class="playable-code">
ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 100, 100);</textarea>
```

**JS**

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var textarea = document.getElementById('code');
var reset = document.getElementById('reset');
var edit = document.getElementById('edit');
var code = textarea.value;

function drawCanvas() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  eval(textarea.value);
}

reset.addEventListener('click', function() {
  textarea.value = code;
  drawCanvas();
});

edit.addEventListener('click', function() {
  textarea.focus();
})

textarea.addEventListener('input', drawCanvas);
window.addEventListener('load', drawCanvas);
```

Comment: i assume, it can be done by area tag, but somewhere i see, its best to use canvas api or svg. I want to know, for this type of task, which approach is best?